# Writing to 2 or more different data layers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

looking for a way in rails to allow me to write into 2 different data layers (databases) at the same time. first layer being the most important and should hold the request until finished, others can be processed in the background.

for example if i have a Person model and i create a new one, i want the entry to be save in MongoDB for example but later saves to MySQL, cassandra and so on.

any ideas and links are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about any rails solution but there is one java based ORM that can help you in achieving exactly this.

You can try exploring https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera. You would love it.

Kundera is a JPA 2.0 compliant Object-Datastore Mapping Library for NoSQL Datastores and currently supports Cassandra, HBase, MongoDB and all relational datastores (Kundera internally uses Hibernate for all relational datastores).

In your case you can use your existing objects along with JPA annotations to store them in Cassandra,MongoDB, MySQL etc.

Since this is in java you can build a java based service that you call from your rails app.